# Sumproduct within date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I'm using this formula to sum some data according to 4 criteria:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Data!$A$2:$A$518=Sheet2!A2)*(Data!$D$2:$D$518=Sheet2!$E$1)*(Data!$E$1:$AW$1>=C2)*(Data!$E$1:$AW$1<=D2)*Data!$E$2:$AW$518).
```

The formula is set up so that the third and fourth criteria are used to identify a date range that is established in cells c2 and d2 of "Sheet 2".

When I evaluate the formula I notice it is not evaluating the date ranges as I would expect.  Excel is assigning "TRUE" values to all the dates when executing the `(Data!$E$1:$AW$1>=C2)` segment and "FALSE" values to all dates when executing the `(Data!$E$1:$AW$1<=D2)` segment.  There are dates in the data ranging from 2017 to 2020 and the current range I'm working with is December 2018 to November 2019, so the range is within the data.

This causing the formula to return 0 as the value.

The other sections of the formula appear to be working as expected.

I've checked my formatting and all relevant cells are formatted as dates.

Are there any other suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the "dates" in `$E$1:$AW$1` are actual dates and not text that looks like dates?

Comment: Formatting a cell as a date does not make the contents of a cell a date in the eyes of excel.

Comment: `=isnumber(E2)` should evaluate to true if its a date in excel format.  Alternatively if you set the cell format to general, a Excel date will become an integer.

Comment: Thank you both very much, definitely learned something new about formatting.  My original data came from a report and I had assumed it was formatted as a date, apparently Excel disagreed!